Issue with Route Redirection on Angular 18 App Hosted on Azure
I am experiencing an issue with my Angular 18 application hosted on Azure. When accessing the application at the URL yyy.net (free plan), it correctly redirects to yyy.net/home. However, when I attempt to navigate to the login page by clicking the login link, I encounter the following error:
Error: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
It seems that the login route is not being handled correctly by the server, although the route is properly configured in the Angular routing setup. All other routes (e.g., /home, /signup) work as expected, but the /login route fails to load.
Could you please assist in resolving this issue or provide guidance on any required configuration for routing within the Azure environment?
my app route `
export const routes: Routes = [

    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }, ....`

app component html:
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>


Hi @mateus, can you please share your config file with more details.

tanks, i solved

Solved. Add this to your web.config file in dist/[build]/browser/:
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

